# how to end session of an android application in an efficient way?

Tags: android

i would like to close all the connection to the server side when application crashes. The application runs a main activity which holds my menu. under this activity there are at least 7 fragments and i would like that if the application crashes, all the connections of the current session will be terminated. I know there is the onDestroy method but i am not sure how to use it or if it will solve my problem.

in addition i already implemented a logout() function but it will be executed in case the user clicked on logout.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)?

Comment: i read that but i didn't understand if i move to fragment from the main activity does the onStop() function will be activated?